# Error on expo simulator build at _configureExpForAssets

Tags: expo

My build was rejected by the app store, who said it crashed on launch. The app runs fine through expo, so I tried a simulator build but it fails with this output:

```
Checking if there is a build in progress...

Publishing to channel 'default'...
Warning: This project contains unoptimized assets. Please run `expo optimize` in your project directory.
Building iOS bundle
Building Android bundle
Analyzing assets
Uploading assets
No assets to upload, skipped.
Processing asset bundle patterns:
- /Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/QMG-local/APPS/ELECTRO/**/*
Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at _configureExpForAssets (/@expo/xdl@55.0.13/src/Project.js:1037:26)
```

I have no clue what this means, can anyone help? The actual ios build succeeds.

Comment: Having same issue. Did you find any solution @Jonathan Tuzman ?